# Web service Client giving error : package xyz does not exist

Tags: java, web-services

So i created a web service and hosted it on tomcat.
I picked up the wsdl url and generated a web service client using net beans.
After creating the function in the client side and calling the web service method, i get the following error :

```
    error: package xyz does not exist
    xyz.CentralizedMethodsService service = new xyzCentralizedMethodsService();
```

Following is my calling method :

```
private static String getRawHtml(java.lang.String arg0) {
    xyz.CentralizedMethodsService service = new xyz.CentralizedMethodsService();
    xyz.SEI port = service.getCentralizedMethodsPort();
    return port.getRawHtml(arg0);
}
```

Any solution ??

Comment: check if stubs (client classes) are generated properly ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your 'war' file have the required libraries. check the tomcat/webapps//WEB-INF/lib/ have the required jar files

why you use 'xyz.CentralizedMethodsService' syntax, why cant you import the class and use the class name to instantiate Object.

Comment: the war file has required libraries and all are present in the needed folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you try running your new Java application without first building your project, NetBeans will not have parsed your WSDL (which contains the link to your client service) and thus will be unable to find the package your WSDL links to. To fix, simply right-click on your project and choose "Clean and Build," then try running your Java application again.